# Why DC supply voltage is increasing when inverter is connected to powerful three phase induction motor?

Tags: motor, ac, inverter, induction-motor

[image]

If I connect my inverter to a resistive load or small inductive load the DC supply voltage (in my application it is 56 V) stays constant. However, if a powerful induction motor is connected, the DC supply voltage gradually increases. The gradual increment might be due to the soft starting feature that gradually increases the PWM duty cycle from 20% to 90% to minimize the effect of a high starting current. The final DC bus voltage reaches 85 V if I attach 200 µF capacitors across DC positive and negative terminals and 100 V if I connect 100 µF. I assume the additional power comes when both high side and low side MOSFET are off due to dead time generation.

How do I solve this issue? Is it necessary to add a resistor to discharge the power that comes when both MOSFETs are off? I think the circuit of the freewheeling diode (here the body diodes) is not complete without a resistor across positive and negative terminals of the DC supply.

Comment: What feeds 56 V DC into the system?

Comment: SMPS via an extra full bridge rectifier to block reverse current.

Comment: Have you tested the regulation loop of said SMPS? Most droop voltage with increasing load, but some don’t. My last purchase had an effective cable loss overcompensation “feature”. Within specs, but nonetheless increase with load.

Comment: I bet it doesn't happen when the motor is mechanically loaded.